# Derivative of Dirac delta

Tags: algorithms, partial-derivative, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

To represent formally the part of an algorithm

> if $r \in [0,p (\mathbf{v})]$, set $y = A(\mathbf{v})$; else set $y = B(\mathbf{v})$,

where $\mathbf{v}$ is a vector of parameters and $r$ is a uniform random variable $ r \sim \mathrm{U}(0,1)$, it is possible to use a formalism with Heaviside step functions $\Theta$:

$$
1 = \int \mathrm{d}y \; \int_0^1 \mathrm{d}r \;
\Big[ \Theta\left[ p(\mathbf{v}) - r \right] \delta(y - A(\mathbf{v}))
+
\Theta\left[ r - p(\mathbf{v}) \right] \delta(y - B(\mathbf{v})) \Big]
$$

I am trying to take the partial derivative of this expression with respect to $v_i$.

The derivatives from the theta-functions are clear enough, but I'm having trouble with the delta functions. On general grounds I think it should generate terms proportional to $\partial A / \partial v_i $ and $\partial B / \partial v_i $, but if I apply the usual result for the derivative of a Dirac delta, I don't get any. In addition to this, the usual derivation is related to integration by parts, but here there is no $\mathrm{d} v_i$ integral which makes me suspicious I'm missing something.

I understand that distributions can be tricky, so expect there's a subtlety I'm missing here.  If anyone can help, I'd appreciate it if you could clarify (if you know!):

- Is the idea here conceptually problematic?
- If not, is there a way to make this work?
- Has anything similar to this been written up anywhere?

Comment: There is a lot of context missing, you should really explain your situation from the beginning. For example, why are you bothering with the integrals at all? What is $y$? How does $p(v)$ relate to any of the other functions (if at all?)

Comment: I think the context is mostly irrelevant, but in case it helps, $p$ here corresponds to the probability of choosing $A$ and $1-p$ of $B$; $y$ is a variable that would be used elsewhere. The fact that it evaluates to 1 allows this expression to be inserted somewhat akin to a 'resolution of the identity' into a larger expression for a more complicated algorithm. The integrals allow the discrete algorithm to be represented and manipulated formally.

Comment: What are the bounds for $y$? The fact that you think the context is mostly irrelevant is a little annoying considering you wanted the subtleties regarding distribution theory - usually that entails taking the integration all the way through before taking derivatives unless you have a good reason.

Comment: As a concrete example, is there a reason why we can't simplify the equation to $$1 = \int dy \Bigr[p(v)\delta\left(y-A(v)\right)+(1-p(v))\delta\left(y-B(v)\right)\Bigr]$$ ?

Comment: I say irrelevant purely because I think the question is well-posed as written. The bounds for $y$ can be $-\infty,\infty$ without loss of generality for our present purposes. I don't quite follow your last sentence; is there a reason why we can't 'differentiate under the integral sign'?

Comment: Regarding your second comment - yes, that is a possible simplification (apologies; I misread earlier)

Comment: I did the integration correctly. The theta functions are essentially indicator functions for the intervals $[0,p]$ and $[p,1]$, respectively.

Comment: To answer your question, there is no differentiating under the "integral sign" in distribution theory because the integral sign has been abstracted away. And I was wrong in an earlier version of this comment, could you elaborate why your naive (and honestly probably accurate) application of product rule failed when you differentiated?